# Черный экран при запуске LibGdx Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Учусь создавать игры при помощи `LibGdx` по книге "LibGDX Game Development By Example" (James Cook). В английском не силен, так что в основном беру только исходники и пытаюсь разобраться сам.
Нашел там урок по созданию платформера, переписал код с книги, добавил немного своего кода для обработки нажатий и возникла такая проблема: при первом запуске приложения - черный экран, т.е. все загруженные элементы не отображаются, а если нажать кнопку "Домой" и снова вернуться в приложение, то все нарисовано так, как должно быть.

Проект Eclipse в Github: https://github.com/pmaprog/AndroidGame

В чем проблема? Помогите, ломаю голову уже 2 дня. Спасибо!

Comment: Сомневаюсь что это поможет, но на всякий случай попробуйте в манифест добавить android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: @anber, к сожалению не помогло, но я нашел решение. Немного поигравшись с функциями и переменными, я достиг желаемого результата. Проблема заключалась в Viewport. Не буду описывать, что именно я сделал, но если вам интересно, можете посмотреть правки кода в GitHub.

Comment: @anber, https://github.com/pmaprog/AndroidGame/commit/d6dc3f1f703198d3ab5200ceb6a1508906daa6ba

Comment: Рекомендую удалить папку bin удалить, закомитить, запушить, а затем добавить ее в .gitignore чтоб ее не было в репозитории и чтоб она больше там не появлялась.